# Can anyone explain this algorithm for calculating large factorials?

Tags: c++, algorithm, factorial

i came across the following program for calculating large factorials(numbers as big as 100).. can anyone explain me the basic idea used in this algorithm??
I need to know just the mathematics implemented in calculating the factorial.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

      unsigned int d;

      unsigned char *a;

      unsigned int j, n, q, z, t;

      int i,arr[101],f;

      double p;


    cin>>n;
    p = 0.0;
    for(j = 2; j <= n; j++)
        p += log10(j);
    d = (int)p + 1;
    a = new unsigned char[d];
    for (i = 1; i < d; i++)
        a[i] = 0; //initialize
    a[0] = 1;
    p = 0.0;
    for (j = 2; j <= n; j++)
    {
        q = 0;
        p += log10(j);
        z = (int)p + 1;
        for (i = 0; i <= z/*NUMDIGITS*/; i++)
        {
            t = (a[i] * j) + q;
            q = (t / 10);
            a[i] = (char)(t % 10);
        }

    }
    for( i = d -1; i >= 0; i--)
        cout << (int)a[i];
    cout<<"\n";
    delete []a;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where did you come across the algorithm?  You should *always* include this information to give proper attribution, but it might also be helpful in answering the question.

Comment: If this isn't the penultimate example of why writing readable code is a big bonus, then I don't know what is. This code does not deserve an explanation, it deserves a rewrite.

Comment: What is this algorithm name ?

Comment: IMHO, there is a bug. Is should be `a = new unsigned char[d+1];`

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Note that

```
n! = 2 * 3 * ... * n
```

so that

```
log(n!) = log(2 * 3 * ... * n) = log(2) + log(3) + ... + log(n)
```

This is important because if `k` is a positive integer then the ceiling of `log(k)` is the number of digits in the base-10 representation of `k`. Thus, these lines of code are counting the number of digits in `n!`.

```
p = 0.0;
for(j = 2; j <= n; j++)
    p += log10(j);
d = (int)p + 1;
```

Then, these lines of code allocate space to hold the digits of `n!`:

```
a = new unsigned char[d];
for (i = 1; i < d; i++)
    a[i] = 0; //initialize
```

Then we just do the grade-school multiplication algorithm

```
p = 0.0;
for (j = 2; j <= n; j++) {
    q = 0;
    p += log10(j);
    z = (int)p + 1;
    for (i = 0; i <= z/*NUMDIGITS*/; i++) {
        t = (a[i] * j) + q;
        q = (t / 10);
        a[i] = (char)(t % 10);
    }
}
```

The outer loop is running from `j` from `2` to `n` because at each step we will multiply the current result represented by the digits in `a` by `j`. The inner loop is the grade-school multiplication algorithm wherein we multiply each digit by `j` and carry the result into `q` if necessary.

The `p = 0.0` before the nested loop and the `p += log10(j)` inside the loop just keep track of the number of digits in the answer so far.

Incidentally, I think there is a bug in this part of the program. The loop condition should be `i < z` not `i <= z` otherwise we will be writing past the end of `a` when `z == d` which will happen for sure when `j == n`. Thus replace

```
for (i = 0; i <= z/*NUMDIGITS*/; i++)
```

by

```
for (i = 0; i < z/*NUMDIGITS*/; i++)
```

Then we just print out the digits

```
for( i = d -1; i >= 0; i--)
    cout << (int)a[i];
cout<<"\n";
```

and free the allocated memory

```
delete []a;
```

Comment: Indeed - +1 from me.  I'd give it more if I could.